# Attaching library while compiling to 11g

Tags: javascript, oracle11g, migration, oracleforms

I have problem frmjdapi library. I wrote script for compiling Oracle forms, menus and librarys from 6i to 11g. I found AttachedLibrary, but it only attaches Oracle librarys to menus and forms. How do I attach library to library using this class or there exist something else?

Comment: you should post an answer indicating how it was solved so that it'll help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method is simple, when you convert pll file to pld all librarys is listed in top of pld
by format:

```
.attach LIBRARY some_library END NOCONFIRM\r\n
```

So before compiling pll convert it to pld and add library to the back of the list. Then convert it back to pll and you have attached library.